# Install Antivirus protection Software (bitdefender) on elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera

Tags: software-installation, release-hera

I tried to install Bitdefender Antivirus protection on the last Elementary version 5.1.2. but it did not work with the command line.

(I want to use bitdefender, because I use it for my W10 and Mac devices)

Q1 is it possible at all?
Q2 how do I do this when it is possible?
Q3 if it is not possible with bitdefender , is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Bitdefender is proprietary software.  It is up to them to provide a version for Linux.

edit - I mean a home version.  they have endpoint for business users.

edit 2 - I should have included some alternatives.  If you are comfortable with the command line, try Sophos.  That is what I use.  Ages ago I used a trial of ESAT NOD32 and it was quite good, but a little intrusive.

Consider if you really need an antivirus.  I just use it as I share a lot of files with windows computers and don't want to pass on a virus from a windows file.  there are very few actual Linux viruses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a antivirus in Linux, there are almost no viruses for Linux and when a vulnerability for the Linux kernel the community solves the problem in less than a few hours. I've been using Linux for over a three years and never caught a single virus.

Comment: Not true at all. Partially you are right, but not to the end. I recommend to install ClamAV and scan once a week the whole hard drive.